# Check if interactive form exists in ColdFusion before using cfpdfform action="read"

Tags: pdf, forms, coldfusion

I'm using cfpdfform to read values from an uploaded PDF form created in Adobe LiveCycle and then filled in using Adobe Acrobat.

To read the form values I use the command:

```
<cfpdfform source="#pathToNewPDFFile#" action="read" xmlData="xmlFields" />
```

But if a PDF without a form is uploaded (i.e some other PDF) ColdFusion errors with the following:

```
The source PDF document is not an interactive form.
```

Is there any way I can test for the presence of a form in a PDF in ColdFusion without needing to catch and interpret this error?

I've tried `cfpdf action="pdfinfo"`, but none of the variables appear to change between an interactive and non interactive form.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do a simple

```
<cftry>
  <cfpdfform source="#pathToNewPDFFile#" action="read" xmlData="xmlFields" />
  <cfcatch>
    <cfset xmlFields = XmlNew()>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: You have a typo: 'xfcatch' should be 'cfcatch'

Comment: Hi, this is pretty much what I've done - my quesion is more is there a way do do this without using error handling e.g. some property or function I can call.

Comment: Is something wrong with error handling here? I mean, it *is* an error, right?